# Instruction overwrites previous Result

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering, disassembly

I am currently analyzing a binary and came across the following three instructions:

```
movzx   ecx, byte [rax+r9]
movzx   edx, byte [rbx+r9]
lea     ecx, [rcx+rdx]
```

The meaning of each of these instructions is clear to me, but the first and third in combination do not make any sense. The first movzx copies the value at [rax+r9] into ecx and afterwards ecx is overwritten again by the lea instruction? Why do we need the first movzx here?

I guess I am just missing something and this is a nasty compiler trick, so I appreciate any help.

Comment: `ecx` and `rcx` share the same lower 32 bits, so the first instruction sets up an argument for the third.

Comment: Not seeing this cost me hours - thank you very much!

Comment: Just to make it clear, counter-intuitively, moving to `ecx` sets **all** bits of `rcx`, so the state of upper 32 bits of `rcx` before executing the code does not matter.